# Spark & Scala: Generate DataSet (or Dataframe) with given size

Tags: scala, apache-spark

For evaluation purposes, I need a function that creates a dummy-`Dataset` (or, alternatively a`DataFrame`), initialized with random numbers. The dimensions in terms of columns and rows should be parametrized

I came up with a solution, but that is absurdly slow (5.3s for 10 rows with 100 columns):

```
def createDummyDataset(rows : Int, columns: Int, spark: SparkSession) = {
   import spark.implicits._

   var ds = Seq.fill(rows)(Random.nextDouble).toDF()
   if (columns > 1) {
      for (i <- 2 to columns) {
         ds = ds.withColumn(i.toString, rand)
      }
   }
   ds // return ds
}
```

Is that due to the architecture of Spark or am I doing something completely wrong and there is a much better way?

I guess a better way would be to define some kind of matrix and convert that to a `Dataset` at a blow. But I was not able to figure that out.

System: Spark 2.1.0, Scala 2.11.8, Ubuntu 16.04, i5-6300U, 32GB RAM

Answer (score 1):

Doing it by adding columns to an existing DataFrame is going to cause a lot of Spark-related overhead.

Better to create a 2D array style collection then parallelize that all in one go:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import spark.implicits._

val data = (0 to rows).map(_ => Seq.fill(columns)(Random.nextDouble))
val rdd = sc.parallelize(data)
val df = rdd.map(s => Row.fromSeq(s)).toDF()
```

Comment: Thanks. Did you try it out? It cuts down the execution time to 3.3s (-61%) for 10 rows and 100 columns. But still, this seems way to long for 1000 cells?

Comment: Yes does seem a little on the slow side. What are you timing - the whole Spark job, or just the initialisation of the dataframe? Initialising the Seq of Seqs should be sub-second. I wouldn't expect Spark distributing a dataset of that size to take over 3 seconds. How long does it take to execute (0 to rows).map(_ => Seq.fill(columns)(Random.nextDouble)).toDF().rdd.collect() ?

Comment: I'm timing just the initialization... Also, your code results in a `DataFrame` that has only one Column holding an Array of numbers :(

Comment: Have updated code to give you a Row of doubles, sorry about that. I'm afraid I can't explain why it's still taking 3.3s without taking more time to debug. Can you provide screenshots of the DAG if possible, number of tasks Spark uses to init the DataFrame from the web ui?

Comment: Is there a possibility to access the DAG (:4040) after the job has finished. Even when launching a cluster and submitting I'm not able to hit short window to make a screenshot of the DAG. What I noticed though is that the execution gets faster after the first execution...

Comment: also, an error is thrown: `error: value toDF is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]`, see https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/4186481718746324/4176224149823660/1135393478677886/latest.html

Comment: fixed missing import

Answer (score 1):

Based on ImDarrenG answer, however the output is a data frame with n rows and m columns.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{DoubleType, StructField, StructType}

def start(rows: Int, cols: Int, col: String, spark: SparkSession): Unit = {

         val data = (1 to rows).map(_ => Seq.fill(cols)(Random.nextDouble))

         val colNames = (1 to cols).mkString(",")
         val sch = StructType(colNames.split(",").map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName, DoubleType, true)))

         val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data.map(x => Row(x:_*)))
         val df = spark.sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, sch)

         df.printSchema()

         spark.stop()
    }
```

Running on Spark 2.1.0, Scala 2.11.8, Fedora Scientific,  i5-5200U 4 cores, 16Gb RAM

For 10 Rows x 100 Columns on average elapsed time was 0.9 sec

Comment: [Boern](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1701600/boern), does that answer your question?